# Migrating setLibraryPaths method from 0.6.8 version

Tags: java, renjin

We are migrating Renjin to the latest version and as part of the settings we included a directory with user defined R libs.

How can we migrate the following line ?

```
renjinContext.getGlobals().setLibraryPaths("/home/renjin/r-libs");
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Renjin no longer loads packages from the file system.

Renjin now relies on a [PackageLoader](http://javadoc.renjin.org/latest/org/renjin/primitives/packaging/PackageLoader.html) implementation to locate packages. The default is [ClasspathPackageLoader](http://javadoc.renjin.org/latest/org/renjin/primitives/packaging/ClasspathPackageLoader.html), which simply looks on the Java classpath for packages.

To migrate this code, you can either drop it all together, and just require users to ensure packages are on the classpath, or provide your own implementation of PackageLoader to look for packages at a particular path.

Comment: thanks, we're speaking about r script are we ? do you've an example of usage ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? Here is more discussion on the subject: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/aetherpackageloader/renjin-dev/XFwwGVTRkuY/k0HQJjh1CAAJ

Comment: we'll check, the idea is to have a directory where an end-user can put R packages. For now we've to RFM a bit more :-). Thanks

Comment: Renjin in any case expects packages to be built as JARs, so it might be just a question of configuring your classpath to include an extra directory.